# Simplifying $\frac{ (2x+1) (x-3) }{ 2x^3 (3-x) }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

In simplifying
$$\frac{2x^2-5x-3}{6x^3-2x^4}$$

I got this far
$$\frac{ (2x+1) (x-3) }{ 2x^3 (3-x) }$$

but there aren't same brackets to cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{2x^2-5x-3}{6x^3-2x^4}=\dfrac{(2x+1)(x-3)}{2x^3(3-x)}=\dfrac{(2x+1)(x-3)}{2x^3[-(x-3)]}=\dfrac{(2x+1)(x-3)}{-2x^3(x-3)}=\dfrac{2x+1}{-2x^3}$$

Comment: Thank You For Helping Me!

Comment: @xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx Your welcome!

Comment: Don't forget to write the domain of the given term!

Answer (score 3):

There are!

Don't forget that $(x-3)=-(3-x)$ so you can cancel to give:

$$\frac{-(2x+1)}{2x^3}$$

Just remember that $x\neq 3$ is a requirement else you're dividing by $0$ (Thanks Dr)

Comment: Thank You For Helping Me!

Comment: I have written that and got a $-1$, i think this is a joke!

Comment: You can only cancel if $x\neq 3$!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(2x+1)(x-3)}{2x^3(3-x)}= -\frac{(2x+1)(x-3)}{2x^3(x-3)}= -\frac{(2x+1)}{2x^3} $